# Prove If dim($V$) is even, Then there exists a linear transformation $T: V \rightarrow V$ such that Ker($T$) = Image($T$)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Prove If dim($V$) is even, then there exists a linear transformation $T: V \rightarrow V$ such that Ker($T$) = Image($T$)

I'm having trouble trying to prove this statement. I've tried to use the Rank-Nullity Theorem to maybe show that the dimensions are the same but I don't think that works. Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Take, for example, $\pmatrix{0&0\\1&0}$ if $\dim(V)=2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the dimension of $V$ be $2n$ and construct a basis $\{u_1,\dots,u_n,v_1,\dots,v_n\}$. Now define $T$ by $Tu_i = 0$, $Tv_i = u_i$. It is obvious that $\mathrm{Ker}(T) = \mathrm{span}\{u_1,\dots,u_n\}$, and we also have that $\mathrm{Image}(T) = \mathrm{span}\{u_1,\dots,u_n\}$, so we are done.

Comment: and, by the way, $T^2=0$

Comment: Sorry, but could you explain why its obvious that Ker($T$)=span{$u_1,…,u_n$}? Is this from the Rank-Nullity Theorem?

Comment: No, just from linearity of $T$. if $Tu_i=  0$ for each $i$, then $Tw=0$ for any $w$ in the span of the $u_i$'s. From that we have that the span of the $u_i$'s is a subset of the kernel. To see that they are equal, notice that if $w$ is not in the span of the $u_i$'s it must contain a linear combination of some of the $v_i$'s which do not map to zero under $T$. Therefore the kernel of $T$ only contains vectors that are linear combination fo $u_i$'s.

Comment: ahhhhh. Thank you so much.